# If I can prove f(n) = g(n+1) by induction when n is finite, Can I prove f(n) = g(n) by taking n = $\infty$

Tags: induction, infinity

I have to prove f(n) = g(n) when  $n = \infty$. Now I can prove f(n) = g(n+1) by induction when n is finite. Can I say $f(n) = g(n)$ by taking $n = \infty$?

Comment: No, because $\infty$ is not a natural number.

Comment: How do you define $f(n)$ when $n=\infty$?

Comment: You're saying that you can prove $f(n) = g(n+1)$ for each natural number and that, instead, $f(n) = g(n)$ should hold. Note that, combining these expressions, $g(n) = g(n+1)$, hence, $g$ is a constant function, whereby also $f$ is a constant function. Is this consistent with the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: No. Imagine f(n)=Sin(n) and g(n)=Sin(n-1). They don't even converge. You will need something more to prove your statement.